# Help on Complex Analysis Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Q1) How do we integrate $\log(z-6)$ along circle given by the region $|z|=3$ ??

Q2) Let $f(z)$ be an entire function satisfying $|f(z)|\leq k|z|$ for some positive constants $k$ and all $z$. Show that $f(z)=az^2$ for some constant $a$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Note: These are two separate questions, and should be posted separately. It also will help us to help you if you let us know what you've tried, what you know, where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: Q1: What branch of $\log{z}$ are you using? Q2: $f(z)=z$ is a counterexample, so the question is wrong.

Comment: Q2 is false. Consider $f(z)=z$. Surely you meant $f(z)=az$. Then apply Liouville to $f(z)/z$ extended by $f'(0)$ at $0$.

Comment: @MARTEN thanks for the reply :) can you please elaborate the general procedure to go about it without going into the specifics ? the question doesnt mention any branch so i guess it will be the standard which is used

Comment: @julien Thanks for the reply !! The question i have mentioned is correct (as given in the question paper). can you think of something ? what about the first question ?

Comment: @user74167 Then Q2 is either a typo, or it is false as shown by the counterexample $f(z)=z$. For Q1, you need a determination of the complex logarithm which is holomorphic, say, on $\{\mbox{Re} z<0\}$. Then you can simply apply Cauchy's integral formula to $(z-3)\log(z-6)$ at $3$, for the given circle. This will yield $0$. I assume you meant $\int_\gamma \log(z-6)dz$. If you mean $\int_\gamma \frac{\log(z-6)}{z-3}dz$, then it will be $\log(-3)=\ln 3+i\pi$ modulo $2i\pi$, depending on your choice for the $\log$.

Comment: @julien may be i will check Q2 with my teacher then.

I am sorry but i didnt quite understand the solution suggested for question 2. i understand that in the circle given (with radius 3 and centred at origin) the given function i.e log(z-6) is not analytic everywhere so we dont directly apply cauchy theorem to say that integral is zero. what so we do then ??

Comment: @user74167 If Q1 insists on doing this for the principal branch of log, then you will have to do some contour integrals to compute the conrtibutions of each semi-cricle, below and above the $x$-axis.

Comment: There is no such limitations. the question doesnt say anything about which branch to use

Comment: If you take a log which is holomorphic on the left half-plane, then yes, Cauchy's theorem, or Cauchy's integral formula, says that your integral is $0$. But if the question does not says anything, I fear they mean the principal branch of log, in which case it is not as easy and, I think, there is now way around some contour integrals over half-disks.

Comment: Maybe there is a shortcut, actually. You have $\log z=\log (-z)+i\pi$ a.e. for the principal branch of log. So this takes you to the right-half plane where you can apply Cauchy's theorem. So, unless I'm severely mistaken, this will give $0$ in any case.

Answer (score 1):

#### For Q1:

If you are using the so called *natural branch* of $\log{z}$, which requires $0<\arg{z}<2\pi$, then $\log(z-6)$ is analytic on and inside the circle $|z|=3$. Then you can use Cauchy's integral theorem.

The other "standard" branch of $\log{z}$ is the so called *principal branch*, and it requires $-\pi<\arg{z}<\pi$. This is the most commonly used branch, as it is defined for positive real numbers (and has $\log{x}=\ln{x}$ there). In your problem though, $\log(z-6)$ is not defined along (or everywhere inside) the whole curve $|z|=3$, which makes it harder to compute the integral.